# In Angular, is there a way to "provide" a component, similar to a service?

Tags: angular, components, angular-providers

I have an abstract component `AbstractPageComponent` (an abstract class describing a component), the template of an instance of which can contain an instance of another abstract component. Specifically, an instance of `AbstractPageComponent` will contain a component with a list of entities (people, for example). The component with the list of entities is itself an instance of another abstract component, `AbstractListComponent`. I want to access this child component with a `@ViewChild()` decorator. However, simply writing `@ViewChild(AbstractListComponent)` doesn't work. So, right now I have to manually declare the `ViewChild` properties for each instance of `AbstractPageComponent`:

```
// task page component
@ViewChild(TaskListComponent) private readonly listComponent!: TaskListComponent;

// employee page component
@ViewChild(EmployeeListComponent) private readonly listComponent!: EmployeeListComponent;
```

This seems really excessive. I was wondering if there's a way to "provide" a different component to each instance of `AbstractPageComponent`, similar to a service? Something like:

```
import { AbstractListComponent } from '...';

@Component({
    template: ''
})
export abstract class AbstractPageComponent {
    @ViewChild(AbstractListComponent) public readonly listComponent!: AbstractListComponent;

    ...
}
```

```
import { TaskListComponent } from '...';
import { AbstractListComponent } from '...';

// TaskListComponent extends AbstractListComponent

@Component({
    ...
    providers: [
        {
            provide: AbstractListComponent,
            useClass: TaskListComponent
        }
    ]
})
export class TaskPageComponent extends AbstractPageComponent { ... }
```

Comment: Yeah if you provide it, it become available to the injector (if all the constructor parameters are injectable).

Comment: I'm not really trying to inject it like a dependency, I just want some universal way to be able to pass different instances of an abstract component to another component. The last code snippet is there just to make what I want clearer for everybody reading this. Injecting a component like a dependency will only work if I make it `@Injectable()`, which (as far as I know) makes it a singleton, which is a whole other story.

Answer (score 1):

yes, it is possible. Just use `useExisting` for the provider piece. Just remember that there providers would be available in the components subtree only.

```
providers: [
        {
            provide: AbstractListComponent,
            useExisting: TaskListComponent
        }
    ]
```

in this example existing instance of TaskListComponent would be injected when something would try to inject AbstractListComopnent

`@Injectable()` without `provideIn: 'root'` rather tells angular to precompile the service, so it's constructor would inject some services that you are injecting there. You can provide random class somewhere and then use it as a service even without Injectable annotation if it has no dependencies (there is however no reasons to do it)

Answer (score 0):

What about (I don't check)?

```
export abstract class AbstractPageComponent<T> {
    @ViewChild(T) public readonly listComponent!: T;

    ...
}
```

and

```
export class TaskPageComponent extends 
             AbstractPageComponent<TaskListComponent> { ... }
```

Comment: `T` is not a value and only exists on the typescript types level. it will never work

Comment: ::glups:: apologist for your time :(